# networking - router/gateway during a power outage

Tags: linux, networking, nfs, gateway

I have two computers connected via Cat 5e to a simple switch (dumb). The switch itself is wired (Cat 5e) to my home router. The router is also the LAN gateway:

```
router: 192.168.0.1
computer 1: 192.168.0.2  gateway = 192.168.0.1
computer 2: 192.168.0.6  gateway = 192.168.0.1
```

The computers and the switch are all on UPS(es), but the router is not. Thus when the power goes out, and the computers and switch are still operational but the router is not. In this case the two computers cannot communicate with each other. (The two computers use NFS so I would like to preserve the network connection if possible.)

Now the obviously solution is to simply attach the router to an UPS. Which is what I actually did. But this got me thinking about hardening against failures in general, and the edge case where the router crashes.

Here is the actual question: Is there a way to configure the routes on the computers such that they communicate directly with each other? They would still need a gateway for normal operation, but if the router fails, they can still communicate.

(Computers are Linux based. Assume all connections are wired and there is no wifi in this scenario.)

Comment: They both should be able to communicate as they are in the same subnet - double check the subnet mask sent on both of the machines.

Also you say a dumb switch, are you sure it's not a hub? However, still the machines should be able to communicate without the gateway.

Comment: "(Computers are Linux based. Assume all connections are wired and there is no wifi in this scenario.)" - sounds like this is a homework question, is it?

Comment: @djsmiley2k, Given I'm already overeducated, no... this is just my curiosity and not my homework :). Also, I'm sure the two computers are connected via a network switch and not a hub.

Comment: If they can't communicate without the router being on, you are not giving us enough information or there is a missing piece... Communication between these 2 devices does not involve the router/gateway in any way, whether on or off, it should not be relevant actually.

Comment: > If they can't communicate without the router being on, you are not giving us enough information or there is a missing piece...

Here are some additional pieces of information, maybe they are relevant ,maybe not.

* Both computers use DHCP for their IP address. Additionally, the router, dd-wrt, is setup to give static IPs to the two computers via their MAC addresses. 
* Both computers are use Debian testing. computer 1 is configured manually in `/etc/networking/interfaces`. computer 2 uses NetworkManager for its configuration.

Comment: Unplug the router, ping from each computer. You don't need a router unless your packet leaves the subnet destined for outside of your lan.